# how to parse images array from json format to tabelview

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, codable

[image: Plea]

hello i have json data like below

```
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "test",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "Test",
      "id" : "45",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Further Investigation \/ Maintenance Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_fzvXhnBwpw1547270966.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "test",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "Ahmedabad",
      "id" : "47",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_UNQbzzwTaK1547616334.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "shhsge",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "Shsg",
      "id" : "57",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "ewfewf",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "retested",
      "id" : "58",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_8edaM4H6lZ1548233123.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_KhDXUhCHRN1548233123.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_zIhztQ2mVD1548233123.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_I3RWeD0VKl1548233123.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_VuDzsyR5gI1548233123.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "sadsad",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "dads sad",
      "id" : "59",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_n19NGjRfcH1548233550.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_WQn8zZeT0X1548233550.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_GYF21A9lMd1548233550.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_eaeoXVIPbU1548233550.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_w7KTfkTtdT1548233550.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "sadsad",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "adds",
      "id" : "60",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_fVghhQFhB31548233912.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_k3Y5CaQIsj1548233912.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_nVhXpintD51548233912.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_gS0wahnPzZ1548233912.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_TT2RZF2Pnv1548233912.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "sadsad",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "sad sad",
      "id" : "61",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Further Investigation \/ Maintenance Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_iy7hMFz69u1548234019.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_799ad8B4aj1548234019.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_5HFLk03Fgp1548234019.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_9zYgQKVqQ51548234019.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_UYf49scKwn1548234019.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "sdsadas",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "daddy’s sad sad",
      "id" : "62",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Further Investigation \/ Maintenance Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_htPOrErbgF1548234575.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_Y4ms5mkzgD1548234575.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_nuFk2NsfzV1548234575.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_IRpxGQb72s1548234575.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_N0w9sCwNcM1548234575.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "N\/A",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "sadsa",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "8",
      "locations" : "asdsadas",
      "id" : "63",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Further Investigation \/ Maintenance Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "4",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Floors",
      "contravention" : "27",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_jJj0URkS9o1548234685.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_GU95bP9bhn1548234685.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_Arob8rq0QU1548234685.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_79Erayiurr1548234685.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_T8m2dxSmI91548234685.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Damaged wooden floors"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "Test test",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "26",
      "locations" : "Kitchen",
      "id" : "11",
      "boiler_service_date" : "0000-00-00",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "",
      "regulation_id" : "6",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Gas",
      "contravention" : "202",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_j9QNiQ9Sun1548225475.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_zVBEjnkZf41548225475.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_LTaxAfGTZW1548225475.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_Mj5D6otfhX1548225475.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_DQTfucDObS1548225475.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "Condition and certs"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "35",
      "locations" : "",
      "id" : "6",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "7",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Items",
      "contravention" : "210",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "4 ring hob, oven and grill in good working order"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "test test",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "35",
      "locations" : "",
      "id" : "7",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Extractor To Be Vented Out \/ Mechanical Fan To Be Installed",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "7",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Items",
      "contravention" : "210",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_1Ot5YN8xL11548151400.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "4 ring hob, oven and grill in good working order"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "test test",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "35",
      "locations" : "",
      "id" : "8",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Extractor To Be Vented Out \/ Mechanical Fan To Be Installed",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "7",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Items",
      "contravention" : "210",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_9vhD62hRcp1548151402.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "4 ring hob, oven and grill in good working order"
    },
    {
      "resolved" : "",
      "type" : "Internal",
      "notes" : "Test Test",
      "property_id" : "22",
      "regulation_item" : "35",
      "locations" : "",
      "id" : "9",
      "boiler_service_date" : "",
      "action" : "Maintenance Attention Required",
      "intervention_required" : "N\/A",
      "regulation_id" : "7",
      "regulation_item_name" : "Items",
      "contravention" : "210",
      "images" : [
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_SbrrQxWl2A1548151619.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_ly1adD9T3C1548151620.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_qVup3MTUHh1548151620.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_4Asw2j3YF61548151620.png",
        "http:\/\/christies.buildingcontrolregister.ie\/webservice\/assets\/uploads\/inspection_photo\/img_y0FAbTekMh1548151620.png"
      ],
      "contraventions_item_name" : "4 ring hob, oven and grill in good working order"
    }
  ],
  "total_count" : "1",
  "success" : "1",
  "message" : "Previous inspection list."
}
```

form this data i am getting data `array` but not able to display on `tableview`  and also i am not able to understand how to fetch images array form that data here is my code for populating my `tableview`

**Code**

```
func PreviousInspeList(){
    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
    let uid = "u_id"
    let acTkn = "acc_tkn"

    let u_ID = preferences.object(forKey: uid)
    let A_Token = preferences.object(forKey: acTkn)

    let params = ["user_id": u_ID!, "access_token": A_Token!,"property_id": propertyID!]
    print(params)
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.request(previousinspectionslist, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let value):
            let json  = JSON(value)
            print(json)
            let data = json["data"]
            data.array?.forEach({ (iList) in
                let inspList = PreviousInspListModel(resolved: iList["resolved"].stringValue, type: iList["type"].stringValue, notes: iList["notes"].stringValue, property_id: iList["property_id"].stringValue, regulation_item: iList["regulation_item"].stringValue, locations: iList["locations"].stringValue, id: iList["id"].stringValue, boiler_service_date: iList["boiler_service_date"].stringValue, action: iList["action"].stringValue, intervention_required: iList["intervention_required"].stringValue, regulation_id: iList["regulation_id"].stringValue, regulation_item_name: iList["regulation_item_name"].stringValue, contravention: iList["contravention"].stringValue, contraventions_item_name: iList["contraventions_item_name"].stringValue)
                self.preInspData.append(inspList)
            })
            self.tblListView.reloadData()

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        case.failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
}
```

here my model class

```
struct PreviousInspListModel {
    var resolved: String
    var type: String
    var notes: String
    var property_id: String
    var regulation_item: String
    var locations: String
    var id: String
    var boiler_service_date: String
    var action: String
    var intervention_required: String
    var regulation_id: String
    var regulation_item_name: String
    var contravention: String
    var contraventions_item_name: String
}
```

i just mean to tell why my data not is populating on `tableview` and how to get images `array` and also display on `tableview` please help me on this

Comment: do you want to show all images ?

Comment: yes i want to show all images which are in the array

Comment: please some one help me

Comment: can you show your tableViewCell structure ?

Comment: pelase check i have added and screens hot of my tableview cell structure

Comment: @Ajaysaini pelase help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell` to show all the images. and use your Images Array for populating the `UICollectionView`. find the great tutorial for adding `UICollectionView` inside `UITableView` Cell

https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

```
struct PreviousInspListModel {
    var resolved: String
    var type: String
    var notes: String
    var property_id: String
    var regulation_item: String
    var locations: String
    var id: String
    var boiler_service_date: String
    var action: String
    var intervention_required: String
    var regulation_id: String
    var regulation_item_name: String
    var contravention: String
    var contraventions_item_name: String
    var imageArray: [String]!
}
```

in your loop :

```
data.array?.forEach({ (iList) in
                let inspList = PreviousInspListModel(resolved: iList["resolved"].stringValue, type: iList["type"].stringValue, notes: iList["notes"].stringValue, property_id: iList["property_id"].stringValue, regulation_item: iList["regulation_item"].stringValue, locations: iList["locations"].stringValue, id: iList["id"].stringValue, boiler_service_date: iList["boiler_service_date"].stringValue, action: iList["action"].stringValue, intervention_required: iList["intervention_required"].stringValue, regulation_id: iList["regulation_id"].stringValue, regulation_item_name: iList["regulation_item_name"].stringValue, contravention: iList["contravention"].stringValue, contraventions_item_name: iList["contraventions_item_name"].stringValue, imageArray: iList["images"].arrayObject as? [String])
                self.preInspData.append(inspList)
            })
```

Comment: Yes but how to get images array from data

Comment: define an array for images in you model. and assign the image array when you casting data in the model in loop

Comment: will you please be more specific i can't understand

Comment: did you able to populate the tableView using the data ??

Comment: Yes i populate successfully just issue of that images array

Comment: i am not able to fetching only images array from response

Comment: check my answer

Comment: i am getting error like this for `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[String]?'`

Comment: means after `imageArray: iList["images"]` what i put stringValue on any other?

Comment: add .array?  make it imageArray: iList["images"].array?

Comment: .stringValue cast value to String Type

Comment: if i put `.array?` then i am getting error like this `Cannot convert value of type '[JSON]?' to expected argument type '[String]?'`

Comment: if i put `imagesArray: iList["images"].arrayObject as? [String]` then i am getting result exactly i want

Comment: Yes now i want to populate this array in tableview so how can i populate please help me

Comment: you have to implement a UICollectionView inside your tableView cell.

Comment: but i have only value images then how can i take collectionview any other simple way

Comment: if you want dynamic images then collectionView is good. you can also do this by adding imageViews programmatically

Comment: Yes sure if you feel my question is good so please upvote my question

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 release, Apple unveiled a brand new way of [data encoding and decoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) protocols by conforming your custom types with some easy to adopt protocols

1) Encodable — for encoding

2) Decodable — for decoding

3) [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) — for both encoding as well as decoding

It provides support for class, struct and enum as well.

By conforming Codable protocol you have to create your model class as response format, no need to parse data manually.

In your example:

```
struct ResponseData : Codable {
    let message: String
    let data : [PreviousInspListModel]
}

struct PreviousInspListModel : Codable {
    let resolved: String?
    let notes : String
    let type: String
    let images: [String]
}
```

In your Api response function:

```
Alamofire.request(previousinspectionslist, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData { (responseData) in
            responseData.result.ifSuccess {
                if let data = responseData.data{
                    do {
                        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data) //Decode JSON Response Data
                        print(response)
                    } catch let parsingError {
                        print("Error", parsingError)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You can find more detail about [`swift 4 codable`](https://hackernoon.com/codable-in-swift4-e24f7cc253da) or just search the term on web.